# "Invalid argument" or "No such file or directory" during mounting a shared folder between Win 7 Host and Ubuntu 10.10 Guest

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, ubuntu-10.10, shared-folders

Host is Windows 7 and has e:\uShared as a folder to be shared with VB Guest
Ubuntu 10.10

Guest is Ubuntu 10.10 and has home/darius/shfolder to be used to share files 
with host OS.

I have gone to VB Guest Device\Shared Folders and added e:\uShared with full access.

From guest Ubuntu 10.10 I have:

Run the following command

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=1000,gid=1000 uShared /home/darius/shfolder
```

and I got this

> /sbin/mount.vboxsf: mounting failed
>   with the error: Invalid argument

so I tried

```
sudo mount.vboxsf uShared home/darius/folder
```

and got this error

> mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the
>   error: No such file or directory

Why is this happening and what do I do to fix it?

Comment: Have you created `/home/darius/shfolder`?